# MDB Pool & Thred pool configuration in Websphere Application Server 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere-6.1

I am using Websphere Application Server (WAS) 6.1

Can someone asist me to configure max MDB pool size & max thread pool size for that particular MDB ? I need to execute one MDB instance in one thread only, there will not be more than 1 execution at a time.

Comment: And your concrete question is? The deployment descriptor editor should provide everything you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a poor idea for scalability.  It seems better to handle the concurrency at the database level (or whatever transactional system the MDB is operating on).

If you really believe it is necessary, you can simulate a singleton MDB by setting the [poolSize](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rejb_ecnt.html) property to H1 ("hard" instance max of 1) for your EJB.  This will cause the EJB container to create at most one instance of your EJB, which means each thread that would deliver a message to the MDB will block waiting for the instance to become available.

```
-Dcom.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.poolSize=YourApp#YourModule.jar#YourEJBName=H1
```

It is not possible to configure a per-MDB thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need concurrent processing (which is what MDB are typically used for) you can limit `maximum sessions` parameter for listener port this MDB is bound to in WAS.